# Count how many times every product has been ordered

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Each `Order` in the database has a `product_id`.  There is only one `Product` per order.

From the `ProductsController`, I want to show all the products, and next to each one a number of how many times it has been ordered. I will need to include a condition to exclude any products that have `deleted = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should return the results you need.  Adjust as needed with conditions, additional fields, etc.

```
$data = $this->Order->find('all',array( 
   'fields'=>array(
       'COUNT(Product.id)as Count',
       'Product.id','Product.name'
   ), 
   'group'=>array(
       'Product.id'
   ), 
   'contain'=>'Product' 
));
```

Answer (score 3):

I would also use [counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count)

Add an order_count field to your Product table and modify Order model as so

```
class Order extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Product' => array(
            'counterCache' => true,
            'counterScope' => array('Product.deleted' => 0)
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: +1 Although I can't use this in my scenario due to some non-standard usage.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `find('count')` should suffice (details of this find operation are in [the Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-count)):

```
// Get a list of all the active products
$products = $this->Product->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('Product.deleted' => 0)
));

// Loop over the products
foreach($products as $product_id => $product) {
    $count = $this->Product->Order->find('count', array(
        'conditions' => array('Order.product_id' => $product_id)
    ));
    echo "There were " . $count . " orders for " . $product;
}
```

As suggested by Mark, a `GROUP BY` should also do the trick and simplifies the process by using just a single find.

```
$count = $this->Product->Order->find('count', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Order.product_id' => $product_id,
        'Product.deleted' => 0
    ),
    'group' => array('Order.product_id')
));
```

Comment: I wonder if "group by Product.id" could make this in a single query

Comment: @mark Good point, I think you're right. I updated the answer to show that method as well.

Comment: Your updated answer still has you making a separate query for each product which could add up fast. Try:
$data = $this->Order->find('all',array(

   'fields'=>array('COUNT(Product.id)as Count','Product.id','Product.name'),

   'group'=>array('Product.id'),

   'contain'=>'Product'

  ));

Comment: additionally, using virtual fields here it should be a pretty well structured find result.

Comment: I was really hoping to do it in one query, as it will be very inefficient otherwise.  Oldskool, your second method didn't work unfortunately.  I just got a single count.

Comment: @LeGrande Your method works perfectly, thank you.  Please post separately so I can select as the correct answer.